# How to reverse a trackbar's range ? (commctrl.dll)

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, slider, controls

I'd like to use a comctrl.dll trackbar for sound level adjustment, with the lowest value at its bottom and the highest at the top, reversed from the normal situation but I can't do it.
The **TBS_REVERSED** flag doesn't seem to really have any effect on the slider, and reversing the min and max values in the **TBM_SETRANGE** message is not supported. Doing it individually with **TBM_SETRANGEMIN** & MAX either…

```
HWND hwndTrack = CreateWindowEx(
        NULL,                               // no extended styles 
        TRACKBAR_CLASS,                  // class name 
        L"Trackbar Control test",              // title (caption) 
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | TBS_AUTOTICKS | TBS_VERT | TBS_TOOLTIPS | TBS_DOWNISLEFT | TBS_REVERSED,              // style 
        10, 44,                          // position 
        30, 200,                         // size 
        hwnd,                         // parent window 
        (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_TRACKBARTEST,                     // control identifier 
        GetModuleHandle(NULL),                         // instance 
        NULL                             // no WM_CREATE parameter 
        );
    SendMessage(hwndTrack, TBM_SETRANGE,
        (WPARAM)TRUE,                   // redraw flag 
        (LPARAM)MAKELONG(0, 127));  // min. & max. positions
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this, would be to reverse the result.

Something like:

```
result_value = max_value - trackbar_value;
```

And the other way round to set the value.

Comment: Yes, that is the workaround I intend to use until, if possible, there is a way to do it directly in the control.

Comment: This seems the only solution if the control doesn't support it itself.